# How do I stop a running PowerShell command in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I cannot find how to stop a running PowerShell command using a keyboard shortcut. My command is:

```
do {ping 127.0.0.1} until (Test-Path -Path C:\Users\foobar)
```

How can I stop this command using a keyboard shortcut?
I can press the recycle bin icon but that kills my PowerShell extensions completely and VS Code then asks to restart it.

I tried some commands on the internet like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, but it does not stop the execution.

Answer (score 1):

*(migrated from a comment by [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf))*

> [The default command for ending a running PowerShell script or command is] just like in the console: 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: That does not work from Visual Studio If you are running a Python file that executes a PowerShell script

Comment: @EricBellet you would need to look up how to pause a Python script/program if you are running a Python file.

Comment: To stop Python script with Visual Studio is just using the Stop button, however, the Powershell script that I am calling from Python is still running

Comment: @EricBellet Yes, that's a more complicated situation that would call for its own question. This question was how to stop a PowerShell script running within Visual Studio. I'm not sure you can stop a PS script in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use shortcut : CTRL+BREAK / CTRL+C

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Ctrl+Break allows to kill a powershell command in Visual Studio.